# If you malloc a struct* does it create local variables?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Feel free to edit the title if it doesn't make sense. So I've been using `malloc` for a while without really being completely sure of how it works. If I create an int pointer and set it equal to `malloc(10*sizeof(int)`, I figure that it allocates a block in memory of 10 times the size of one int, then returns the starting address of this allocation, but nothing is actually initialized within that memory yet. Am I OK so far?

Now say I create a struct for linked list nodes like this:

```
typedef struct node_ {
    int data;
    struct node_ *next;
} Node;
```

and then have a create linked list function:

```
Node* LLCreate(int data) {
    Node *head = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if ( head != NULL) {
        head->next = NULL; // don't get how malloc created `next`
        head->data = data; // or `data`
    }
    return head;
}
```

What I don't get, and can't seem to google appropriately, is, if `head` is just the starting location in memory of an empty block of size `Node`, and not an actual variable, how does it have the local variables of `next` and `data`?

Maybe this is a nonsensical question because I have some fundamental misunderstanding of what's going on here, but if anyone understands what I'm trying to ask and could clear this up for me I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: `head` is a *pointer to* (i.e. the *address of*) the memory allcoated by malloc.

Comment: A variable is just a region of storage (plus a type). There's nothing magical about "being a variable".

Comment: so malloc actually creates the struct in memory, it doesn't just allocate space for it?

Comment: "Creating a struct" doesn't really mean anything. Types are a compile-time concept, not a runtime concept.

Comment: If you google for `head` you might get some interesting results. There is a technique in googling in choosing the rarer words to search for

Comment: It just allocs space for the struct. But the space for the struct contains the space for the fields in the struct so that sizeof(Node) >= sizeof(int) + sizeof(Node*). Each of the fields of the struct lives at a particular offset into the memory that was allocated for the struct.

Comment: `next` and `data` are simply offsets from the start of the block of memory that you've allocated, and it's a convenience for the programmer. That's all.

Comment: Ok so when you allocate space for a struct it also keeps track of the local variables it has and the offsets needed for them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesnt have local variables like `next` and `data`.

`next` and `data` are just used to calculate the address relative to from where `node` is pointing.

When you do `node->data` then the address is calculated as `address pointed by node + (total bytes required by any metadata for malloc) + 0` because `data` is the first member of `node` struct.

And when you do `node->next` then the address is calculated as `address pointed by node + (total bytes required by any metadata for malloc) + sizeof(data)` , because `next` is the second member of the `node` struct that comes after `data` member.